# How to solve the following compilation error in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My `.aspx` looks like the following:

```
<div id="valueIntroduction" type="text" class="labelarea" runat="server">  
  <input name="$labeluniversityid" type="text" id="labeluniversityid" style="color:#7D110C;border:0;background-color:#C0D5F2;width:100%" />
</div>
```

.cs File looks like:

```
    if (results.Read())
    {
       labeluniversityid.value = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
    }
```

Exactly what am trying do is am getting the data from the database and displaying it in the `valueIntroduction` div. That is workiing fine. Now i added a text box with `readonly` mode. So that in my page if I press `EDIT` button, the value could be edited.

Comment: The name 'labeluniversityid' does not exist in the current context

Comment: this is error which I got...

Comment: Orelse is there any other way I could achive this?

Comment: Just curious, why are you not using <asp:label ..>

Comment: The main reason of me creating that page is to put an edit button to edit the details in the database. So I need to use TEXT BOX for this purpose right? am I moving in right way?

Comment: Am i missing something?

Comment: On a side note, your `div` shouldn't have a `type`  attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a TexBox component:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="labeluniversityid" runat="server" CssClass="yourcssclass"></asp:TextBox>
```

As for the styling:

```
.yourcssclass
{
color:#7D110C;
border:0;
background-color:#C0D5F2;
width:100%
}
```

Then, in your code behind you can easily use it like this:

```
labeluniversityid.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
```

Keep in mind that ASP.NET Controls are translated into common HTML tags, so you can wrap it and style it as you would with any other normal input of type text.

Also: `type="text"` is not valid for `div`

Comment: This is directly using the text box right? I want to use inside a div!!! This works fine for text box alone...

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from wrap the textbox inside the div. Remember that ASP.NET Components are translated into common HTML. So, a TextBox will be translated into an input with type "text".

Comment: Ya I tried.. now it is not showing any error... but i could not see the text box either!!!!

Comment: Where are you executing the code? Also, did you use any breakpoints to see if results["TEXT_CONTENT"] actually has a value?

Comment: Now tell us where are you executing that code, that's likely where your error is.

Comment: Areks I could not see the text box itself... I checked the data and it is getting the data fine...

Comment: I see the div valueIntroduction has been set to run at server and has a Css class, are you sure you aren't hiding with valueIntroduction.Visible = false OR via CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `runat="server"` attribute in `<input id="labeluniversityid">` tag.

Or use a `<asp:TextBox>` control as *areks* suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -

```
runat="server"
```

to your input field

Or, even better, use an

```
<asp:textBox ..>
```

Comment: Wow, I give the exact the same as p.s.w.g, yet I get the downvote?

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote, but I'll give you +1 for what it's worth.